# Explanation of sizeof() with various data types in C++

Tags: c++, sizeof, string-literals

Additional question (1 point): 
Assume we are using 32-bit Windows operating systems
and C/C++ programs. Please estimate the sizeof() for the follows (unit: byte)

```
• char str[] = “Hello” ;
• char *p = str ;
• int n = 10;
Please calculate:
• sizeof ( str ) = __________
• sizeof ( p ) = __________
• sizeof ( n ) = __________
```

Hello All,

I am trying to wrap my mind around this fairly fundamental concept in C++. I will tell you what I think the correct answers are to see if I am on the right track. For the first one, sizeof(str), I believe it is 6 bytes total. I noticed a pattern from other problems that there is always 1 byte added to these types of strings. (5 letters +1). My question is, what is this "+1" from? As for the second one down, this is just referring to the size of a pointer,p, correct? which is always 4 bytes in size? Finally, the third one, I believe is just referring to the size of an int, n. From what I know all ints are of size 4 bytes correct? Does this mean all ints are 4 bytes regardless if its 10 or 10000, or any other number. Any other important info on this topic is also greatly appreciated and accepted with open arms! Thanks!

Comment: The first is 6. The last two depend on the implementation.

Comment: For 32 bit Windows, both ints and pointers are 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[] = "Hello" ;
```

is equivalent to:

```
char str[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

The standard guarantees that `sizeof(char)` is `1`. Hence `sizeof(str)` is `6`.

The size of a pointer and an `int` are always platform dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Ok its my first answer on stackoverflow

**First Question :**

```
 char str[] = "Hello";
```

in C/C++ character arrays need a null termination('\0') or (NULL) to identify the end of the character array, whenever we are reading character array the pointer is placed at the first index and it loops till we find null termination character.Hence its Size is 6.

Note the null termination character varies from compiler to compiler(as per my knowledge) in general they use '\0'.
you can also use zero(0);

```
char s[] = {'H','E','L','L','O',0};
```

or 'NULL'

```
char s[] = {'H','E','L','L','O',NULL};
```

**Second Question:**

```
char *p = str
```

The character pointer 'p' stores the address of the character array 'str'
it points to the first index of the character array and stores the address.
which is of 4 bytes. hence you get

- `sizeof ( p ) = 4 // p holds the address of str`

where as if you had used *p (value at p) then you would have received value as 1.

```
 • sizeof ( *p ) = 1 // Now *p is value at p i.e first element in
                 character array = 'H' which is of size 1 byte
```

**Third Question**

```
int n = 10
```

This obviously is going to give you size as 4 bytes (8 bits) on 32 bit system.

Again the size of also varies from compiler to compiler.

talking about your last question

> Does this mean all ints are 4 bytes regardless if its 10 or 10000, or
>   any other number

The answer is yes and no
For a 16 bit compiler of C/C++ the range for signed int is -32768 to 32767.

For 32 bit compiler the range is -2147483648 to +2147483647

any number (of type signed int) between this range is going to take 4 bytes on a 32 bit compiler like Turbo C

> Any other important info on this topic is also greatly appreciated and
>   accepted with open arms

**Fun Fact**
For above if

```
int n = 2147483648 //note the extra 1
```

is still going to print or store

```
2147483647 in n
```

Try it out (on 32 bit compiler)

Secondly
in C++ for strings i.e

```
string str = "Hello";
• str.size() = 5 // note: its not 6
```

I hope I answered your Question and provided additional information.

Comment: `int n = 2147483648` is Undefined Behavior and may print as 2147483647, 2147483648, -2147483647, 0, or `"you're fired"`, or format your harddisk instead of printing anything.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for pointing "Undefined Behavior", I will remember that.

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed a pattern from other problems that there is always 1 byte
>   added to these types of strings. (5 letters +1). My question is, what
>   is this "+1" from?

That 1 byte is for null termination ie '\0'.
Think about it.

If you use strlen(calculates at run time) instead of sizeof(calculates at compile time), strlen() starts scanning the string at first character, increments the count,moves to next character, there has to be some character at which the string has to mark it's end,right?? that is what null termination is for.

> From what I know all ints are of size 4 bytes correct?
>
> The C++ standard does not specify the size of integral types in bytes,
>   but it specifies minimum ranges they must adhere to.

This is already explained here.
[[What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be][1])

Good practice is to always use standard defines to avoid such confusions.

Look into

> "stdint.h " or "cstdint"

header files if you are on linux. Not sure about windows.

int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t

these make the code more readable.

Comment: `sizeof` does not scan the string for the size.  It is a compile time constant.

Comment: `stdint.h` is the C standard header. [`cstdint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) is the C++ header, not `cstdint.h`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, if we pass an array to `sizeof` we get its length; not the pointer it decays to's size. A string literal is an array of `n` characters with a null terminator.

So for

```
const char str[] = "foobar";
```

`sizeof(str) == 7` because in reality it will be set out in memory like this:

```
const char str[] = {'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', '\0'};
```

This is a compile-time constant and is known by the compiler as soon as the array is defined.

If you take a pointer to that array `const char *strp = str` then `sizeof(strp) == sizeof(char*)`.

---

As for the size of `int` or `T*` (where `T` is any object type), it is implementation defined. But `sizeof(T*) == sizeof(U*) == sizeof(void*)` where `T` and `U` are any object types.

The only guarantee you get is `sizeof(char) == 1`. Anything else is up to the implementation.

From `N4140` (C++14 draft standard)

> **§ 3.9.1 Fundamental types**
>   2 - There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long
>   long int”. In this list, each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.
>   There may also be implementation-defined extended signed integer types. The standard and extended signed
>   integer types are collectively called signed integer types. Plain ints have the natural size suggested by the
>   architecture of the execution environment<sup>46</sup>; the other signed integer types are provided to meet special
>   needs.

So the actual guarantee you get is:

```
sizeof(signed char) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)
```

<sup>*`signed char` is the same size as a `char` but is a distinct type and `unsigned char` is the same size as both but another distinct type again.*</sup>

---

On another note, with most systems it will be like this:

64-bit operating system, `sizeof(T*) == 8`
32-bit operating system, `sizeof(T*) == 4`

and on 64 and 32-bit systems `sizeof(int)` *usually* `== 4`.

<sup>where `T` is any *object* type</sup>

Comment: I don't think `sizeof(T*)== sizeof(void*)` is guaranteed. It's pretty likely that `sizeof(T*) <= sizeof(void*)` because `void*` must be able to hold a pointer to _any_ object, but a particularly evil compiler could add unneeded padding bits to `T*`. Somewhat less evil, a `T*` pointing to an array might hold a cached array size. This would be useful in debug mode. But since there's no `void[ ]` a `void*` might not get that same count.

Comment: @MSalters the size of the array wouldn't be a part of the pointer itself, but rather allocated as a few bytes *before* the pointer. That's how I'd do that if I was gonna do it, anyway. But nah, the standard guarantees that the size of a pointer to object will always be the same size, and `void*` is a pointer to object of unknown type. That's why casting `void*` to function pointer types is undefined behaviour.